# Adding a line to specify the curve on bar chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel file with data which I use to build up a bar chart. Now, I want to have a line indicating the curve, can anyone explain to me how to do it.

https://mmuedumy-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/1201101510_soffice_mmu_edu_my/EavW4H6HJo1JvK1byJaoJ_AB7YaNWXVaAvc9jHnhrOclQQ?e=C6ZNIR - Link for the excel file

[image]